# Query Studio SQL statement to pull data date range function syntax

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I'm using Query Studio in SFMC - Is there a better way to write this query? I checked the DE - I 99% sure there are records to see but doubting myself if I'm writing this correctly.  I'm just trying to show any available data from 1/1/2021 to 3/31/2021.

```
SELECT Last_J_Created_Date 
FROM TA_Cl_Engage
WHERE NOT Last_J_Created_Date >= 2021-31-03 
AND Last_J_Created_Date <= 2021-01-01
```

Comment: Next time I'd suggest providing a sample of the source data and a the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify dates without enclosing them in single quotes or a function.

The `31` and `03` switched in your first date -- should be `YYYY-MM-DD`.

The operators are switched -- `>` means *after*.

```sql
SELECT Last_J_Created_Date 
FROM TA_Cl_Engage
WHERE Last_J_Created_Date >= '2021-01-01'
AND Last_J_Created_Date <= '2021-03-31'
```

The above will inclusively select rows from midnight (0:00) on `2021-01-01` to midnight on `2021-03-31`.

Comment: Thanks! Mr. Spriggs; If I wanted to go back two years, would I use same criteria, but I do not want any records that are between Jan. thru Mar '21 ? 

`
WHERE Last_J_Created_Date >= '2020-03-01'
AND Last_J_Created_Date <= '2022-03-22' <>  
AND Last_J_Created_Date >= '2021-01-01'
AND Last_J_Created_Date <= '2021-03-31'
`

Comment: In that case add the upper bound and just switch the signs and drop the equal signs on the other criteria:  `WHERE Last_J_Created_Date >= convert(date, getDate()-720) and Last_J_Created_Date < '2021-01-01' AND Last_J_Created_Date > '2021-03-31'`

Comment: Thank you @Adam-Spriggs, this worked just fine!

Comment: Hi @Adam-Spriggs do you have another suggestion, I noticed that this only worked if I used an OR statement instead of an AND. 

WHERE Last_J_Created_Date >= convert(date, getDate()-720)  
AND Last_J_Created_Date < '2021-01-01'  
OR Last_J_Created_Date > '2021-03-31'

Comment: Ah, yes, my mistake.  But you'll need to add some parentheses around the `OR` condition -- `WHERE Last_J_Created_Date >= convert(date, getDate()-720) and (Last_J_Created_Date < '2021-01-01' OR Last_J_Created_Date > '2021-03-31')`

Comment: is there a way to use diffdate function or achieve same results using getdate() ?

Comment: Yes, but they're slower, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Why the 'NOT'? The NOT would only apply to the first clause...

Try something like this -

```sql
SELECT Last_J_Created_Date 
FROM TA_Cl_Engage
WHERE Last_J_Created_Date >= 2021-01-01 
AND Last_J_Created_Date <= 2021-31-03
```